# Cassandra - cfstats and meaning of read/write latency

Tags: cassandra

```
Read Latency: 0.10471324863883848 ms.
Write Latency: 0.10803364485981308 ms.
```

What is the meaning of those values?

- Is this average time?
- What is timeline for this calculation? Time since last restart?
- Is it possible to reset Read/Write Latency (over JMX
  maybie)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on if you are talking about the latency values printed for the entire keyspace or the latency values printed for a specific column family.

The latency numbers for the keyspace are the average latency per request for the entire lifetime of the JVM. (total latency/total requests)

The latency numbers for the column family is the average latency per request since the last time that jmx mbean was queried (last time you did nodetoolcfstats).

There is no way to reset the values for the keyspace overall currently, but the column family values reset after each call as I mentioned.

Comment: Your explanation is very useful. Can you give any references for this? I mean about how that 2 (key space n column family) latency values are calculated. Thanks.