# Do Cassandra read latency stats count Secondary Index queries piecewise?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, latency

I am trying to understand whether read latency stats obtained through

- nodetool cfstats
- nodetool cfhistograms

, will count each read within secondary index queries separately.

I guess the answer might depend on whether secondary index queries are handled by thrift clients or internally by Cassandra. I don't know that either.

[1]  [Cassandra - cfstats and meaning of read/write latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431590/cassandra-cfstats-and-meaning-of-read-write-latency)

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra read latency is calculated with calculating average time taken by each read query.

In that a single get query or multiget query is considered as a single read  and average is calculated.[ `StorageProxy.read()` is the function where Cassandra is collecting time taken for each query ]

Comment: Thanks samarth. Do you mind if I ask for a verifiable source.

Comment: see this link http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/0.8.0-beta2/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java

look at the implementation of "read(...)" function and then see how "readStats.addNano(System.nanoTime() - startTime);" this call works you will get the complete idea.

Comment: Thanks I gave you an upvote. I want to wait for some more answers before accepting.